# How do I tell my browser that I have an *equal* preference for two languages?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, language

Apparently, the [HTTP standard supports giving two languages the same preference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language). However, my browser (currently Google Chrome, I'm willing to switch if necessary) forces me to "rank" my languages in the browser settings.

I can read both English and German fluently. If content is available in English with a German translation, I want the English content. If it is available in German with an English translation, I want the German content.

If having an equal ranking of both languages is not possible, I'd also be happy to have "no language preference", so that I get the "default" (non-translated) version of web pages. Again, Chrome does not allow me to remove all languages from the settings.

**How do I tell my browser that I have an *equal* preference for two languages?** (Or, if that's not possible, how do I tell it *not* to send language preferences at all?)

*Note that I am **not** talking about browser translation services. I am talking about web sites offering content in different languages based on the client's `Accept-Language` header.*

Comment: try modifying the `Accept-Language` HTTP header using a Chrome extension. You can fork [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher/iojaoainolpgkpojokmeclhidjolocci) extension, which modifies the default User-Agent HTTP header.